# Why does adding 'dynamic' fix my bad access issues?

Tags: swift

I'm having a strange issue that appeared with iOS 8 Beta 5 (this issue did not occur with previous versions).

I tried to create an empty project and try to replicate the issue, but I'm unable to do so, so I'm not quite sure where the issue lies.

What I'm seeing is that attempting to access methods of a custom `NSManagedObject` subclass results in a strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

For example:

```
  var titleWithComma: String {
       return "\(self.title),"
  }
```

This method, out of many others, causes this issue when called. However, adding a `dynamic` keyword before it makes the issue go away:

```
  dynamic var titleWithComma: String {
       return "\(self.title),"
  }
```

I know I'm not giving enough info, because I honestly don't know how to pinpoint the actual issue, but can anyone explain what is possibly happening, and why adding `dynamic` might resolve this issue?

Answer (score 69):

From Swift Language Reference (Language Reference > Declarations > Declaration Modifier)

> Apply this modifier to any member of a class that can be represented
>   by Objective-C. When you mark a member declaration with the dynamic
>   modifier, access to that member is always dynamically dispatched using
>   the Objective-C runtime. Access to that member is never inlined or
>   devirtualized by the compiler.
>
> Because declarations marked with the dynamic modifier are dispatched
>   using the Objective-C runtime, they’re implicitly marked with the objc
>   attribute.

It means that your property/method can be accessed by Objective-C code or class. Normally it happens when you sub-classing a Swift class of Objective-C base class.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The others are talking about the Obj-C `@dynamic` modifier where the Swift `dynamic` is a distinct thing.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that a class marked `@objc` has all of its members implicitly `dynamic`?

Comment: @devios1: `@objc` and `dynamic` have different concept. Please follow the link for more detail:https://cocoacasts.com/what-does-the-dynamic-keyword-mean-in-swift-3/

Answer (score 2):

This is from the prerelease Swift / Objective-C interoperability documentation:

**Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses**

Core Data provides the underlying storage and implementation of properties in subclasses of the NSManagedObject class. Add the `@NSManaged` attribute before each property definition in your managed object subclass that corresponds to an attribute or relationship in your Core Data model. Like the `@dynamic` attribute in Objective-C, the `@NSManaged` attribute informs the Swift compiler that the storage and implementation of a property will be provided at runtime. However, unlike `@dynamic`, the `@NSManaged` attribute is available only for Core Data support.

So, because of some of the Objective-C runtime features that Core Data uses under the covers, Swift properties need to be specially annotated.

Comment: But in my case, `titleWithComma` is not actually a registered variable of the model, as in, part of the schema. It's more just an instance method, but meant to be accessible without function notation, i.e `()` Or does it still not matter?

Comment: @moby: Core Data uses some pretty sophisticated runtime trickery. Think isa-swizzling and the like… With Objective-C this all just worked, because Objective-C method calls are *always* dynamically dispatched. With that in mind, it's not terribly surprising that Swift users are going to encounter a few rough edges… At least until Apple has more time to polish up the language and / or revise some of the frameworks.