# Use Realm Object Directly (i.e as CollectionView Data Source)

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, realm

So i have this Realm Object class :

```
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class Realm_item: Object {
    var item_ID : String!
 required init() {
            super.init()
        }

        // And this one too
        required override init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
            super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
        }

        // Now go nuts creating your own constructor
        init(myCustomValue: String) {
            self.item_ID = myCustomValue
            super.init()
        }


    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "item_ID"
    }

}
```

Than i am trying to initialize it, but it simply stuck, with no exception or error/crash.

```
  let item = Realm_item(myCustomValue: "SampleString")


  self.dataSource.append(item)
```

Comment: What are those additional initialisers?, try removing them, also the item_ID needs to be declared as dynamic var

Comment: Thank you @Shripada , Ismail gave me detailed answer above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is few comments I have on your code.

- `item_ID` should be dynamic
- it's better to define a default value for `item_ID` instead of making it optional
- you should not to create or override init and only create custom init(s) as convenience
- `import Realm` is not needed `import RealmSwift` is enough.

The code should look like this.

```
import RealmSwift

class Realm_item: Object {
    dynamic var item_ID : String = ""

        // You should only define init(s) as convenience and call self.init() inside it.
      convenience init(myCustomValue: String) {
            self.init()
            self.item_ID = myCustomValue   
        }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "item_ID"
    }
}
```

Then you use it like the way you do.

```
 let item = Realm_item(myCustomValue: "SampleString")
  self.dataSource.append(item)
```

I hope this helps. Thanks.

**Update**:

- What does dynamic keyword mean?? pleas see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039389/1066762)
- Why do we use dynamic variables with realm? as mensioned in [Realm
  Swift Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#optional-properties)

  > Realm model properties need the dynamic var attribute in order for
  >   these properties to become accessors for the underlying database data.
  >
  > There are two exceptions to this: List and RealmOptional properties
  >   cannot be declared as dynamic because generic properties cannot be
  >   represented in the Objective-C runtime, which is used for dynamic
  >   dispatch of dynamic properties, and should always be declared with
  >   let.
- Is it a good practice to use Realm objects as DataSource?  The way
  you are using in the code sample you have dataSource as
  `Array<Realm_Item>` is a good way as the array size will not change
  automatically while the objects will be updated automatically (if
  there is  other part of the code modifying it)

Comment: Thank you Ismail! That's awesome :) . Can you please explain me what Dynamic var means? And, is it a good practice to use Realm objects as DataSource?

Comment: Hi @roimulia, glad that my answer helped you. please see my updated answer regarding your questions.

Comment: Thank you Ismail! Very useful! much appreciated :)