# Why I can't access an element of a class instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently writing an iPhone application in Swift. I have a global class instance of my user database, like this:

```
var currentUser = UserDB()

class UserDB: Object {
dynamic var id:String = "0"

override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
}

var userName: String?
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
}
```

Then I try to print my user info with a print in another class:

```
UserDB {
id = 56826e22971f34731a07ba09;
userName = aze;
firstName = (null);
lastName = (null);
}
```

But if I try to print a single value, it won't works:

```
print(currentUser.userName)
```

Will print:

```
nil
```

Do you have any idea why?

By the way, is it a good idea to deal with user info like this? I put these info inside a Realm database on exit, when going to background, or after account upgrade.

Comment: Shouldn't you also declare the other properties as `dynamic`?

Comment: Hummmm ... That's it ... I removed this properties a week ago because I saw that it was only for value which needs to be kinda "compliant" with Obj-C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140778/why-does-adding-dynamic-fix-my-bad-access-issues

Comment: Please post it as an answer, I think I could not be the only one to run into this problem :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the properties as `dynamic` if you want `Realm` to map them. It seems that you did this only for the `id` property.

```
dynamic var userName: String?
dynamic var firstName: String?
dynamic var lastName: String?
```

Comment: hmm :/ I have a new problem now, `dynamic var sex: Int?` is not possible as I have a `Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C` error, any idea ?

Comment: Try `NSNumber?`, as `Int` has no corresponding `Objective-C` class. This should be another question, as it answers a different topic, though :)

Comment: Yes sure, but it's just a comment, between you and I :p BTW that's working, THANKS !